# Get default swagger index.html in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to load swagger's index.html in memory so that I can parse it into a string and then customize it.
Note: I must not use a custom index.html, I have to use the default one.

```
internal static IApplicationBuilder UseApiDocumentationUI(this IApplicationBuilder builder, string applicationName)
    {
        if (builder is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        }

        var configuration = builder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var apiVersionDescriptionProvider = builder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
        var identityOptions = new MicrosoftIdentityOptions(configuration);
      
        builder.UseMiddleware<ApiDocumentationConfigurationMiddleware>();
        builder.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.DocumentTitle = applicationName;
            // get swagger's index.html in memory, process it then =>
            //options.IndexStream = () => GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("index.html") //add it here
            foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName);
            }

            options.OAuthClientId(identityOptions.ClientId);
        });

        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: Editing the html sounds weird. Are you aware that swashbuckle come with something called a IDocumentFilter? Implementing one gives you the ability to process the generated swagger file. If you need to customize something else that is not part of the swagger file but the pages html you may tell us why and why you can't simply use a different customized html file then.

Comment: I want to customize the UI, with minor modifications related to changing color based on a staging environment. So yes, I want to customize the swagger file itself, I haven't heard of the IDocumentFilter, is there any sample code for the approach you're recommending?

Comment: Sure there is but it won't help with styling the page ;)  At least i don't think so. Via the options you can inject css or javascript. That might be enough for styling the page to your liking. Have a look at this SwashBuckle sample https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/v5.4.1/test/WebSites/CustomUIConfig

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All I need is just to get the auto-generated swagger index.html in memory. Do you know what's the right path to it? I can't find it anywhere in the bin folder.

Comment: When i look at options.IndexStream i see a getter. Maybe you can just read the stream convert it to text, change what you want to change, convert it back to a stream and set it as IndexStream.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. I'll work on that. Thank you! :)

Comment: That is actually what the Swashbuckle middleware already does to use the default html file ;) Look at the source here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/fd25b8d7d08605051b11324c16b86b599d34d1a2/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs#L101

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248601/discussion-between-andi-thomaj-and-ralf).